# Criar "Slide" de imagem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Procurei no google por plugins/bibliotecas para fazer esta função porém não consegui encontrar nada.

Eu preciso criar um "slide" de produtos igual ao de uma loja virtual, como [neste exemplo](http://www.kanui.com.br/moletom-kanui-clothing--co-vedere-195047.html) (porém sem o zoom).

Estou fazendo a requisição das imagens e dos detalhes dos produtos com PHP e Mysql;

a imagem grande está dentro de `<div class="imagem-big_produto"></div>`
e as imagens menores (thumbs) estão em `<li class="lista_thumbs-produto"></li>`

eu gostaria de clicar em uma `li` (imagem menor) e ela aparecesse no lugar da imagem maior em `imagem-big_produto`

Comment: Tipo isso? http://demos.mashitup.de/demo-with-autoscroll/

Comment: Ou isso? http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/

Comment: Ou isso? http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#single-image

Comment: @IvanFerrer nenhum desses, não preciso de slide, fade, zoom, modal nem nada, apenas imagem estática, clicou...trocou.

Comment: Não precisa de plugin pra isso.

Comment: Quer que eu faça um exemplo?

Comment: Se puder eu agradeço.

Comment: Eu fiz lá... @RafaelAcioly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exemplo (utilize apenas o Javascript e ignore formatações, tamanhos, etc):

```
<div class="imagem-big_produto">
   <img id="imagemgrande" style='width:400;height:300'>
</div>

<ul>
   <li class="lista_thumbs-produto"><img src="imagem1" onclick="document.getElementById('imagemgrande').src=this.src"></li>
   <li class="lista_thumbs-produto"><img src="imagem2" onclick="document.getElementById('imagemgrande').src=this.src"></li>
</ul>
```

Se você estiver usando jQuery, este evento pode ser otimizado através de um seletor múltiplo

Espero ter ajudado

Editado: Se vc quiser colocar um ponteiro como se fosse um clique, pode colocar o seguinte css na imagem:

```
style="cursor:pointer;"
```

Comment: Faltou alguma coisa ai não acha? rs

Comment: Sim, faltaram algumas... kkk

Answer (score 0):

É exatamente isso que você precisa então:

**Exemplo:**
http://www.tocadigital.com.br/biblioteca/galeria/

**Download:** http://www.tocadigital.com.br/biblioteca/galeria/galeria.zip

Aqui o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        body {
            background: #fff;
            font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Verdana;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        #content {
            width: 800px;
            margin: 20px auto 0;
            background: #fff;;
        }
        #gallery {
            overflow: auto;
            width: 120px;
            height: 650px;
            float: left;

        }
        #gallery ul li img {
            width: 103px;
            height:115px;
            border: 0;

        }
        #gallery ul li a {
           text-decoration: none;
            border-right: 6px solid #eee;
            display: block;
            margin: 10px 0;
        }
        #gallery ul li.active a {
            border-color: #b5b5b5;
        }
        #gallery ul li a:hover {
            border-right: 6px solid orange;
        }
        #principal {
            padding-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 150px;
            width: 480px;
            height: 640px;
        }
        #principal img {
            width: 480px;
            height: 630px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
        <div id="gallery">
            <ul>
                <li class="item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="img_01"><img src="imagens/thumb/01.jpg" border="0"></a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="img_02"><img src="imagens/thumb/02.jpg" border="0"></a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="img_03"><img src="imagens/thumb/03.jpg" border="0"></a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="img_04"><img src="imagens/thumb/04.jpg" border="0"></a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="img_05"><img src="imagens/thumb/05.jpg" border="0"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="principal"><img src="imagens/01.jpg" onerror="this.src='imagens/error_img.png'" border="0"></div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){

    $('.item').on('click', function() {
        $('.item').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var $element = $(this).find('a').attr('id').replace('img_','') + '.jpg';
        $('#principal img').attr('src', 'imagens/' + $element);
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```